# Is there an API call that allows to disable app updates on Android?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am developing an Android application that has behaviour that should not be interrupted by anything. Basically, if it's running and doing what it's supposed to do, nothing else should be happening on the device.

In order to achieve this I don't want to rely on user in terms of disabling data sync, incoming call ring etc. - and app updates.

It is important for me because even on quad core CPU app updates can cause rest of the system to become slow and unresponsive for short periods of time.

I know that there's an option to disable automatic updates in Google play settings, but I want to do this programmatically. Is there any API call that allows to do this?

Comment: There shouldn't be any outside of perhaps the device owner stuff. The right answer for this is to build your own custom ROM, so that you can control the environment to your heart's content.

Comment: I cannot ask my users to use custom ROM, it's not an option for me.